# How to use WEEK and DAYOFWEEK functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pymssql

I have a simple code written in MySQL which returns the week number based on specific date:

Is there any equivalent in SQL Server? I was trying to use it by none function works

```
WEEK(ADDDATE(date,5-DAYOFWEEK(date)),3)
```

Comment: Hint:  `DATEPART()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DATEPART`

```
DATEPART(dw, '2007-04-21')
```

where `dw` is **DayOfWeek**